# How to fix "ERROR: You cannot publish an instant-enabled Android App Bundle in an installed track." error in google console publish app

Tags: android, google-console-developer

I want to publish an app. this error always pop "ERROR: You cannot publish an instant-enabled Android App Bundle in an installed track." i already provide keys for the app bundle.

I tried to watch a video tutorial for App bundle.

[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp1kk.png)

Comment: Maybe because it's still in beta? What happens if you try to publish in the instant app track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and look at the `dist:module dist:instant="true"`.

Change `true` with `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Instant app enabled bundles must be published to the Instant App production track (not the normal installed app production track). The [instructions for this are here](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle).